# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: On Android P, a class injection can only be applied to BaseDexClassLoader

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, kotlin, android-9.0-pie

Our application is in development process where we are following MVP approach to provide better test coverage by writing unit test cases on our presenter.

Prior to Android P, our test cases were executing without any problem but now after Android P release when we are trying to run test cases on Pixel 2 (Android P), our test cases are failing on following line of code-

```
private lateinit var mPackageInfo: PackageInfo
mPackageInfo = Mockito.mock(PackageInfo::class.java)
```

with following error message -

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Mockito cannot mock this
>   class: class android.content.pm.PackageInfo.
>
> Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
>
> Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: On Android
>   P, a class injection can only be applied to BaseDexClassLoader:
>   net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.MultipleParentClassLoader@a3838ec

---

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you try with making the mPackageInfo variable non-private?

Comment: @0xalihn yes, not working. problem is where i am initializing mPackageInfo using Mockito

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By refering to here https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1376

Try to use the version `2.18.3`

```
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.18.3'
androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.18.3'
```

Comment: implementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.18.3' seems to be working fine now, still the same problem if i use 2.21.0

Comment: Agh, I had the same issue!  Downgraded to 2.18.3 from 2.21.0 and it fixed my problem...